# preg_match multi-byte characters by length

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

I have some data in an India language encoding. I want to remove parts where there are only one or two characters, e.g. this is two characters:

```
ಎನ್
```

but they are multi-byte

I've tried to match these using the regex:

```
'~\b[^ ]{1,2}\b~u'
```

but it is not working. Any idea?

As per the selected answer, the solution in to use the mb_ereg funcions. This worked for me:

```
mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
setlocale( LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8' );
$str = 'ಆರ್‌ ವೆಂಕಟಲಕ್ಷ್ಮಿ ಎಸ್‌ ಎನ್‌ ಎನ್‌ ಪದ್ಮಾವತಿ ಎನ್';
echo $str . "\n";
echo mb_ereg_replace( '\b[^\s]{2,4}\b', ' @ ', $str );
echo "\n";
```

Result:

```
 @ ‌ ವೆಂಕಟಲಕ್ಷ್ಮಿ  @ ‌  @ ‌  @ ‌ ಪದ್ಮಾವತಿ  @
```

This will not work with preg functions.

Comment: So if you did `{4}` instead it would match?

Comment: Seems to work in [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nQ4iD7), wonder if there is an encoding issue in your PHP?

Comment: No. For some reason I just get left the first 1-2 characters of a word.

Comment: I only get one match here: http://regex101.com/r/wQ5cQ6#pcre

Comment: I think the problem may with the use of the \b (word boundary). It seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the multibyte safe functions [`mb_regex_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-encoding.php) and [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php). (I'm not convinced the first one is mandatory. Also try without and see if that is sufficient.)

Comment: @AmalMurali I don't see anything about multibyte support on the preg_match manual page. And there is no multibyte safe preg_* variant. (at least none that start with mb_preg_*)

Comment: How often you get down-voted for offering the correct answer. I know the feeling.

Comment: @KohjahBreese Doesn't matter. Glad to help. So tell us, what the mb_regex_encoding() function a must-have or could it be omitted?

Comment: If I omit the mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8' ); function, I get an undesired result. So this is required. Thanks for your dilligence, may not have solved this otherwise. To the knowledge pool :)